# Android Intent.ACTION_CALL with a calling card

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to call a complex number with the ACTION_CALL intent, similar to a calling card. It looks something like this: (Calling card phone number, calling card pin, actual number to dial.)

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:18005551234,987654#,14325558765");
startActivity(callIntent);
```

However, when the dialer comes up, it only dials the 800 number at the start of the sequence and ignores the rest.

How can I get it to dial the entire number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this works if you encode the number.

```
String num = "tel:"+Uri.encode("18005551234,987654#,14325558765");
```

Note that including "tel:" inside the Uri.encode() call also encodes the :, which breaks the URI.